# What are the origin and geographical spread of the belief that a girl or woman should not wash her hair when she is menstruating?

Tags: folklore

The belief that a girl or woman who is menstruating should not wash her hair has been called an "old wives' tale". Supposed reasons for it have included the idea that at that time of the month her hair will hang limp and not gain body even if washed, and that washing it will give her a headache.

What is the origin of this belief, and what has its geographical spread been?